# How to get all users in a specific "ou" using LDAP filters in PHP?

Tags: php, ldap

In PHP's [ldap_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php) is something like this:

```php
$ldapserver = 'svr.domain.com';
$ldapuser   = 'administrator';
$ldappass   = 'PASSWORD_HERE';
$ldaptree   = "OU=SBSUsers,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=myDomain,DC=local";
...
$result = ldap_search($ldapconn,$ldaptree, "(cn=*)") or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
```

we can select a specific subtree using `$ldaptree`. I'm using [Laravel LdapRecord](https://github.com/DirectoryTree/LdapRecord-Laravel) package and it only allows using filters during synchronization process.

Can you offer me a filter to select all users who have `(OU=Users)` in their `dn`?